# Decoding custom Python types from JSON files

Tags: python, json

I have a .json file with the following format:

```
[
  "__datetime.datetime__",
  2020,
  5,
  10,
  7,
  56,
  32
]
```

and .py file:

```
import json
from datetime import datetime


def decode_time(t):
    if '__datetime.datetime__' in t:
        return datetime(*t[1:])
    return t


with open('time_data.json', 'r') as time_data:
    data = json.load(time_data, object_hook=decode_time)

print(data)
```

Now my expected value for the variable 'data' should be of type datetime.datetime.

However all what I keep getting is a simple list:

```
['__datetime.datetime__', 2020, 5, 10, 7, 56, 32]
```

Can you please tell me why?

**EIDt**:
I was able to fix this by changing my encoder code:

```
import json
from datetime import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta


def encode_time(t):
    if isinstance(t, dt):
        return {'__datetime.datetime__': True,
                'year': t.year, 'month': t.month,
                'day': t.day, 'hour': t.hour,
                'minute': t.minute, 'second': t.second}
    else:
        type_name = t.__class__.__name__
        raise TypeError(f"Object of type '{type_name}' is not JSON serializable")


now = dt.now()
later = now + timedelta(days=30)

with open('time_data_function_encoder.json', 'w') as time_data:
    json.dump([now, later], time_data, default=encode_time, indent=2)
```

my encode_time function used to be like this:

```
    def encode_Time(t):
        if isinstance(t, dt):
            return ['__datetime.datetime__', t.year, t.month, t.day, t.hour, t.minute, t.second]
        else:
            type_name = t.__class__.__name__
            raise TypeError(f"Object of type '{type_name}' is not JSON serializable")
```

SO now instead of writing an array to the JSON file I'm writing a JSON object in which case the object-hook argument applies.

But now I want to know how I can decode a datetime.datetime object without having to use a JSON object and by just using the array of year, month, day...attributes of a datetime.datetime object.

Comment: `object_hook` is only used for JSON objects, not arrays.

Comment: I'm sorry, but how am I using `object_hook` with an array?

Comment: Square brackets in JSON are arrays, objects are represented with curly braces.

Comment: I see, thanks! Would you mind telling me how would I go about decoding the datetime.datetime object from the `.json` file above?

Comment: Since you can only customize objects, not arrays, I think the solution you found is the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by changing my encoder code:

```
import json
from datetime import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta


def encode_time(t):
    if isinstance(t, dt):
        return {'__datetime.datetime__': True,
                'year': t.year, 'month': t.month,
                'day': t.day, 'hour': t.hour,
                'minute': t.minute, 'second': t.second}
    else:
        type_name = t.__class__.__name__
        raise TypeError(f"Object of type '{type_name}' is not JSON serializable")


now = dt.now()
later = now + timedelta(days=30)

with open('time_data_function_encoder.json', 'w') as time_data:
    json.dump([now, later], time_data, default=encode_time, indent=2)
```

my encode_time function used to be like this:

```
    def encode_Time(t):
        if isinstance(t, dt):
            return ['__datetime.datetime__', t.year, t.month, t.day, t.hour, t.minute, t.second]
        else:
            type_name = t.__class__.__name__
        raise TypeError(f"Object of type '{type_name}' is not JSON serializable")
```